# (Semi-)decidable sets and infinite sets

Tags: logic, computability

I’m confused about the notion of (semi-)decidable sets in the context of transition systems.

Suppose we have some transition relation $\rightarrow$ over some infinite set of states $\Sigma$. Let’s say the set $\Sigma_T \subset \Sigma$ is the set of terminal states (also infinite). Given a starting state $\sigma$ we can now define a function $T(\sigma)$ by $T(\sigma) = \{ \sigma’ \in \Sigma_T \mid \sigma \rightarrow^{*} \sigma’ \}$, where $\rightarrow^{*}$ is the transitive closure of $\rightarrow$. Thus, $T(\sigma)$ is the set of terminal states that we can end up in if we start in state $\sigma$.

My question is: what can we say about the decidability of the set $T(\sigma)$ for a given $\sigma$ and how does this relate to its (in)finiteness? More precisely:

- The relation $\rightarrow$ may be such that $T(\sigma)$ is infinite. Suppose it is. Does this alone imply that $\sigma’ \in T(\sigma)$ is undecidable/semi-decidable?
- Suppose for a given state $\sigma$ there is only one execution path $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma_1 \rightarrow \sigma_2 \rightarrow \ldots$ that never reaches a terminal state. Thus an attempt at computing the terminal states starting with $\sigma$ will never terminate. Does this imply that $T(\sigma)$ is undecidable, even though it is not an infinite set?

Comment: Partial answer: In your second case where there are no terminal states, we have $T(\sigma) = \emptyset$. In $\mu$-calculus, we can write $\sigma \models \nu Z.(\diamond \top \land \square Z)$ iff $T(\sigma) = \emptyset$, so in that case it is enough to check whether $\sigma$ satisfies the formula (model checking is decidable for $\mu$-calculus), and if it does, then $\sigma' \notin T(\sigma)$ for any $\sigma' \in \Sigma$. I would guess that $T(\sigma)$ is decidable in general, but I am not sure how to show it at the moment.

Comment: Do you allow infinite branching?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the application that I have in mind has no infinite branching.

Comment: In the case of finite branching, $T(\sigma)$ will always be semi-decidable. To check whether $\sigma' \in T(\sigma)$, simply do a breadth-first search from $\sigma$, and if we ever reach a terminating state, then check if this state is $\sigma'$. If $\sigma' \in T(\sigma)$, then it will be found in finite time; otherwise the search may run forever.